# How to fix this unexpected behavior while reading from a file in python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read this simple file line by line in python:

```
q(A) p(B)
q(z) ∼p(x)
```

Then from each line I strip the `newline` and then add it to list.

```
lst = []
f = open("input.txt", 'r')

t1 = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
t2 = f.readline().rstrip('\n')

lst.append(t1)
lst.append(t2)

print lst
```

Well the problem is that when I print the content of the list I get the following output:

```
['q(A) p(B)', 'q(z) \xe2\x88\xbcp(x)']
```

My file contains the tilde character `~` and I think this causes that behavior. The weird thing is that if I would print the content of the `t1` and `t2` they would appear normally, but printing the content of the `lst` would appear different

**EDIT: Answer**

Well I managed to get exactly what I expected. In case anyone encounter the same problem may refer to this solution:

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open("input2.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8')

lst = []

t1 = f.readline().rstrip('\n')  
t2 = f.readline().rstrip('\n')  

res1 = ""
res2 = ""

for i in xrange(0,len(t1)):
    if ord(t1[i]) == 8764:
        res1 += "~"
    else:
        res1 += chr(ord(t1[i]))

for i in xrange(0,len(t2)):
    if ord(t2[i]) == 8764:
        res2 += "~"
    else:
        res2 += chr(ord(t2[i]))


lst.append(res1)
lst.append(res2)

print lst
```

And the output now is as below:

```
['q(A) p(B)', 'q(z) ~p(x)']
```

Comment: This is behaving as expected. Printing normally prints the string, while printing the list prints the *representation* (as if via `repr`), i.e. how you would create this string in Python.

Comment: @hlt I need to read more about python.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate IMHO. You were expecting the Latin tilde character but you got the unicode tilde operator. I was puzzled too until I looked up the unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

The file has UTF-8 encoded data. The tilda charater is actually encoded by the `'\xe2\x88\xbc'` string. When you print it, it looks "normal" because something is converting those character to it's equivalent unicode glyph.

Use either `codecs.open` or `decode` functions to obtain your expected data. E.g.

```
f = codecs.open("input.txt", 'r', 'utf8')
```

You should see `u'\u223c'` instead of `'\xe2\x88\xbc'`

Also note that you have codepoint [U+223C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/223c/index.htm) in your file, but you probably intended to use [U+007E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7e/index.htm).

Comment: Just to emphasize, there are multiple tilde's in the unicode spec. You've got the [tilde operator U+223c](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/223c/index.htm) which is different than the [tilde character U+007e](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007e/index.htm).